# Symfony Query Field from associated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine, associations, entity

I have two entities with associations between:

```
Labs\CatalogBundle\Entity\ProductExtraspecs:
type: entity
table: orders__regmat__extraspecs

fields:
    regmatid:
        id: true
        type: integer
        scale: 11
    specid:
        id: true
        type: integer
        scale: 11
    attrib:
        type: string
        length: 20
    value:
        type: string
        length: 200

lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


manyToOne:
  specs:
    targetEntity: Specs
    inversedBy: specs
    joinColumn:
        name: specid
        referencedColumnName: specid
```

And

```
Labs\CatalogBundle\Entity\Specs:
    type: entity
    table: orders__regmat__extraspecs__specs
    fields:
        specid:
            id: true
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
        desc:
            type: string
            length: 200
            fixed: false
            nullable: false
        cat:
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false
        type:
            type: integer
            unsigned: false
            nullable: false

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


    oneToMany:
        specs:
            targetEntity: ProductExtraspecs
            mappedBy: specs
```

So in the controller I want to get all rows with `regmatid = 8` and `cat = 0` and tryed this:

```
$selRepository = $this -> getDoctrine() ->getEntityManager()->getRepository('LabsCatalogBundle:ProductExtraspecs'); 
    $query = $selRepository->createQueryBuilder('sel')
                        //->select('count(c.protid) as cnt')
                        ->where("sel.cat = '0' AND sel.regmatid = $id")
                        //->setParameter('price', '19.99')  
                        ->getQuery();
    $selected = $query->getResult();
```

But get an error saying:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 74 near 'cat = '0' AND': Error: Class
>   Labs\CatalogBundle\Entity\ProductExtraspecs has no field or
>   association named cat

How can I access a field of an associated entity?
Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Will have to join the Specs Table:

```
$selRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('LabsCatalogBundle:ProductExtraspecs'); 
$query = $selRepository->createQueryBuilder('sel')
    ->leftJoin('sel.spec', 'spec')
    ->where("spec.cat = '0' AND sel.regmatid = $id")
    ->setParameter('price', '19.99')  
    ->getQuery();
$selected = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you thats it.. but by the way.. this `$selected` was created to be set as `data` in a `entity Field Type` in a form... but its not working.. do you have any sugestion? Tahnk you again..

Comment: Btw, better is to create a method in your repository so that your controller doesn't contain all the model logic for retrieving data [Trimming Fat from Controllers](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2012/10/31/symfony2-trimming-fat-from-controllers/)

Comment: Adriano, I did no see any protid, but you can try `->select('count(c.protid)')` and instead of `->getResult()` I would use `->getSingleScalarResult()`